# Recyclerview with multiple View Types: inner workings?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have been able to create a RecyclerView that can host two different ViewHolders, depending on data in my model. I am still confused however, on how the RecyclerView and corresponding Adapter make this work.

My reasoning is as follows: when working with only one viewType, the RecyclerView uses the Adapters *onCreateViewHolder* method to create as many ViewHolders as are necessary to fill one screen. This amount is probably less than the total amount of rows needed. 
After creating each ViewHolder, it asks the Adapter to bind the model data to a ViewHolder using *onBindViewHolder*
When scrolling through the list, the RecyclerView always reuses the same ViewHolders, but binds different data to them using the *onBindViewHolder* method from before. It can do this without problems because there is a 1-1 relation between model and viewType.

When there are multiple viewTypes however, I get confused. 
In my use case, there is only a small difference between the two viewtypes. Type A has just two TextViews, type B has the two textViews **and** a Button. I made an Abstract SimpleHolder ViewHolder class that has the two TextViews. For type A the concrete class doesn't do much except call the superclass constructor. For type B I also extend that abstract superclass, and have an extra attribute for the Button.

Say that on my list that of the first 10 items, 5 are of type A, and 5 of type B (randomly placed). The RecyclerView has to create the ViewHolders, and sees that it has to create 5 ViewHolders for type A, and 5 for type B.  It knows which one to use when because I implemented the *getItemViewType* method and use the viewType parameter in *onCreateViewHolder*. 
I guess internally it could look something like this:

1. ViewHolder A
2. ViewHolder A
3. ViewHolder B
4. ViewHOlder A
5. ViewHolder B
6. ViewHolder B
7. ViewHolder A
8. ViewHolder B
9. ViewHolder A
10. ViewHolder B

The numbers here are the positions on the screen. When the user doesn't scroll, all is fine. But once he/she does, things start to change. Position 3 on my screen might not hold a type B anymore, but now a type A. But position 3 is "reserved" for type B! **How does the RecyclerView handle this?**

I can think of the following options, but am not sure.

- The RecyclerView just throws the old ViewHolder away and creates a new one of type A. This is kind of against the idea of a RecyclerView.
- The RecyclerView doesn't actually have fixed positions for its ViewHolder, just a pool. When using one ViewType, it has one pool. When using multiple, it just takes from ViewHolder objects from multiple pools and can reorder them freely. Seems more complex, but doesn't unnecessarily throw away ViewHolder objects.

Is it one of these two? Or something else? Sorry for the wall of text, but I wanted to fully explain my reasoning.

Code if necessary:

```
private abstract class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;

    private Crime mCrime;

    private CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        super(inflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false));
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
    }

    public void bind(Crime crime) {
        Log.d("CrimeHolder", "bind");
        this.mCrime = crime;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mCrime.getTitle() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class SimpleCrimeHolder extends CrimeHolder {

    private SimpleCrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        super(inflater, parent, viewType);
        Log.d("SimpleCrimeHolder", "Constructor");
    }
}

private class SeriousCrimeHolder extends CrimeHolder {
    private Button mContactPoliceButton;

    private SeriousCrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        super(inflater, parent, viewType);
        Log.d("SeriousCrimeHolder", "Constructor");

        mContactPoliceButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_police_button);
        mContactPoliceButton.setOnClickListener(view ->
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contacting Police!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
}


private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    private CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
        this.mCrimes = crimes;
    }

    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        if (viewType == R.layout.list_item_crime) {
            Log.d("Adapter", "onCreateViewHolder - SimpleCrimeHolder");
            return new SimpleCrimeHolder(layoutInflater, parent, viewType);
        } else {
            Log.d("Adapter", "onCreateViewHolder - SeriousCrimeHolder");
            return new SeriousCrimeHolder(layoutInflater, parent, viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder - positie " + position);

        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bind(crime);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.d("Adapter", "getItemViewType pos " + position + " - crime is srs: " + mCrimes.get(position).requiresPolice());
        if (mCrimes.get(position).requiresPolice()) {
            return R.layout.list_item_serious_crime;
        } else {
            return R.layout.list_item_crime;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did you try to stop recycler from recycling the view using `setItemViewCacheSize(int listSize)` ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua I don't have any problems with the code, it works as is. I just want to know why it works.